# Amazon MWS unable to update minimum/maximum prices

Tags: xml, xsd, amazon-mws

I'm trying to set Minimum/Maximum prices for our products on Amazon via mws Feeds API, but I keep getting errors.  Could someone point out my mistake please? Here's sample contents of a feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>IDENTIFIER_VALUE</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Price>
      <SKU>SKU_VALUE</SKU>
      <MinimumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">12.99</MinimumSellerAllowedPrice>
      <MaximumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">63.99</MaximumSellerAllowedPrice>
    </Price>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

This processing result for this feed is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>IDENTIFIER_VALUE</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>XXXXXXXXXX</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary MarketplaceName="www.amazon.de">
                <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>2</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>0</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>90215</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>100% of the products in your file did not process successfully. We recommend using Check My File to help you identify and correct common listing errors before updating your inventory. To use Check My File, upload your file on the &quot;Add Products via Upload&quot; page in the &quot;Check My File&quot; section.</ResultDescription>
            </Result>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>90111</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>The Message/Price/MaximumSellerAllowedPrice field contains an invalid value: 63.99. The value &quot;63.99&quot; is not a valid CURRENCY.</ResultDescription>
                <AdditionalInfo>
                    <SKU>SKU_VALUE</SKU>
                </AdditionalInfo>
            </Result>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>90111</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>The Message/Price/MinimumSellerAllowedPrice field contains an invalid value: 12.99. The value &quot;12.99&quot; is not a valid CURRENCY.</ResultDescription>
                <AdditionalInfo>
                    <SKU>SKU_VALUE</SKU>
                </AdditionalInfo>
            </Result>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

xsd here: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Price.xsd

Thanks!

Comment: What endpoint are you submitting your request to?  If you are using the amazon.com and not an EU endpoint, EUR will be an invalid currency type (from what I am reading)  [Feeds API](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSFeedsApiReference._V135478122_.pdf)  May have some useful information for you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The endpoint was not the problem. I realised that the type for MinimumSellerAllowedPrice/MaximumSellerAllowedPrice was StringOverrideCurrencyAmount. So, changing the values to 12,99 & 63,99 resolved the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved your issue.

Comment: If it is resolved you might want to mark the question as answered so it will not appear in the Unanswered Questions list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MaximumSellerAllowedPrice & MinimumSellerAllowedPrice elements are of type StringOverrideCurrencyAmount.  So, in order for the feed to be processed successfuly those values have to be as specified.  For example the above feed should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>IDENTIFIER_VALUE</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Price>
      <SKU>SKU_VALUE</SKU>
      <MinimumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">12,99</MinimumSellerAllowedPrice>
      <MaximumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">63,99</MaximumSellerAllowedPrice>
    </Price>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Notice how the values changed from 12.99 to 12,99 and from 63.99 to 63,99.

I'm new to stackoverflow so I wasn't aware that I should/could answer my own question.